# Public variable not changed for class child function

Tags: php, variables, scope

Take this class:

```
class A{
  public $test = '';

  public function B($param){
    $this->test = 'hello';
    echo $param;
  }

  public function C(){
    return "C() contains:" . $this->test;
  }
}
```

If I call it this way, passing the output of C into B:

```
$obj = new A;
$obj->B($obj->C());
```

I get this output:

```
C() contains:
```

I would like it to print below because `B` already set `$test` to hello:

```
C() contains:hello
```

Why setting the object's public `$test` variable in `B()` doesn't change the value that the child function call `C()` gets? Don't they both access the same `$obj->test` variable?

Comment: Note that `C` gets called *before* `B`, so the value gets set at the end.

Comment: How can `C` return the value to `B` *before* `B` sets the value…? *cognitive dissonance intensifies*

Comment: My bad, bad morning. Thanks.

Comment: And I thought *I* was having a bad morning today…

Comment: @deceze :) do you think you can remove the hold though? because I did put the desired and actual behavior. I think it could be a valid pitfall to be seen by others. Because I would still be interested for any way of making that possible, if it can be. A bit of a puzzle.

Comment: Quite honestly, with the way the question is phrased, especially the title, I don't think anyone is going to *discover* this. Also, brainfarts don't necessarily replicate that easily. Also, it *is* clear what you want, but it's unclear how you think such a thing could be possible at all, so it's rather *unclear* in the end. Bending over backwards to make this possible is impractical and *too broad* probably.

Comment: @deceze ok no issues. I'll play with it more and reformulate a new question later if still needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You first call `C` method of class `A` which returns `C() contains:`, Now you pass this as `$param` in method `B`, now `$test` has value `hello`, but you just echoed `$param` which was  `C() contains:` so it will print only `C() contains:` to print your desired result you need to `echo $param, $this->test`